# Offer ical file to user to be opened

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, icalendar

I have created a HTML5 app that allows the user to download calendar entries in iCal format. These iCals are created using PHP. My approach until today is to generate the iCal file using PHP and writing it to hard disk on the web server. After that I pass the URL to this file to the front-end (JavaScript) so that it can be opened using the `window.open()` command.

This approach has the drawback that more and more files are being created on hard disk. I understood that there must be another way by adding a specific header to the response sent by the PHP iCal generator. Is this true?

I tried using these headers:

```
header('Content-type: application/force-download; charset=utf-8'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="eintrag.ics"');
```

When calling the PHP generation file directly, the iCal file is correctly displayed in the browser for being opened. But when I am calling this PHP file using AJAX from my HTML5 app, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is "behind the scenes" communication between the user's browser and the server. Requesting data via AJAX will not display it to the user automatically, it simply delivers it to the browser. You are then responsible for acting with that data (displaying it on the page, sending it to the user, etc).

Without knowing more about your architecture, you could try something like (jQuery):

```
$.get('ical/', { param1: 'val', param2: 'val'}, function(response) {
    // we can let the user decide to download the new ical
    message = 'Your iCal is ready, click <a href="' + response.icalPath + '">here to download it';
    $('.message').html(message);

    // or force the user's browser to download the ical file directly
    window.location.href = response.icalPath;
});
```

PHP:

```
// beep boop ... generate iCal

// return the new iCal path to the HTML5 app
return json_encode(array('success' => true, 'icalPath' => 'tmp/icals/generated.ical'));
```

If you really don't want to store the iCal on disk, then you can use a less flexible solution like:

```
window.location.href = '/ical?param=1&param=2';
```

PHP would read the GET parameters, generate the iCal in memory and return with the headers you specified before.

Comment: Hi Matt, 

the first approach you are describing results in two backend calls and the storage of the ical on the web server, right?

I would therefore prefer the second one. Am I able to pass the necessary parameters to php, too? How?

Comment: @AntonSack not really. The first approach asks the server to generate an iCal file, retrieves the URL of the new iCal file, and then it's up to you to do something with that URL. I've updated my answer to have a single approach which I feel offers the most flexibility. I've also added some dummy parameters which PHP can access via GET.

Comment: Matt, you made my day! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a ton. Unfortunately, my reputation is too low to vote for your answer....   :(

Comment: @AntonSack no worries Anton. You can't vote up, but you can certainly accept my answer which will give reputation to *both* of us. Move your mouse under the vote number and click the tick icon.